# Цикл в python в одну строку

Tags: python, массивы, list, циклы, данные

Помогите с кодом, не могу разобраться как сделать перебор списка циклом в одну строку
Суть: нужно в командную строку передать следующее:

```
['44c703adea2b463f8feda2b87454c4e8.1.jpg', '44c703adea2b463f8feda2b87454c4e8.2.jpg', '44c703adea2b463f8feda2b87454c4e8.3.jpg', '44c703adea2b463f8feda2b87454c4e8.4.jpg', '44c703adea2b463f8feda2b87454c4e8.5.jpg', '44c703adea2b463f8feda2b87454c4e8.6.jpg', '44c703adea2b463f8feda2b87454c4e8.7.jpg', '44c703adea2b463f8feda2b87454c4e8.8.jpg', '44c703adea2b463f8feda2b87454c4e8.9.jpg', '44c703adea2b463f8feda2b87454c4e8.avi', '44c703adea2b463f8feda2b87454c4e8.jpg']
```

Нужно, чтобы перечесление элементов из списка было через плюс, пример:

```
44c703adea2b463f8feda2b87454c4e8.1.jpg + 44c703adea2b463f8feda2b87454c4e8.2.jpg + 44c703adea2b463f8feda2b87454c4e8.3.jpg
```

и так далее.

В инете нашел информацию только вывод построчно. А нужно одной строкой, благодарю за помощь.

upd.:

Нужно в одну строку, чтобы это прогнать в командную строку:

```
s = " + ".join(data)
os.system('copy ' + s + ' check.bin')
```

Проблема, что теперь выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/PilotDrowa/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 22, in <module>
    returned_output = subprocess.check_output(cmd) # returned_output содержит вывод в виде строки байтов
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\subprocess.py", line 488, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\subprocess.py", line 1207, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл
```

Comment: ' + '.join(a). И почему именно одной строкой?

Comment: Нужно данные отправить в командную строку

Comment: @ВладиславШвецов Ваш апдейт это другая проблема и другой вопрос. Логичней его отдельно сформулировать и задать отдельно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg']
```

В строковую переменную в нужном виде можно записать так:

```
s = " + ".join(a) # Получаем значение: '1.jpg + 2.jpg + 3.jpg'
```

Сразу вывести на экран так:

```
print(*a, sep=' + ') # На экран выведет: 1.jpg + 2.jpg + 3.jpg
```

Comment: Добавьте как будет выглядеть вывод с вашим примером данных

Comment: 44c703adea2b463f8feda2b87454c4e8.1.jpg + 44c703adea2b463f8feda2b87454c4e8.2.jpg + 44c703adea2b463f8feda2b87454c4e8.3.jpg + 44c703adea2b463f8feda2b87454c4e8.4.jpg + 44c703adea2b463f8feda2b87454c4e8.5.jpg + 44c703adea2b463f8feda2b87454c4e8.6.jpg + 44c703adea2b463f8feda2b87454c4e8.7.jpg + 44c703adea2b463f8feda2b87454c4e8.8.jpg + 44c703adea2b463f8feda2b87454c4e8.9.jpg + 44c703adea2b463f8feda2b87454c4e8.avi + 44c703adea2b463f8feda2b87454c4e8.jpg + 44c703adea2b463f8feda2b87454c4e8.xml